# Unity shared control panel (network)

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine

I have a Control Panel (lots of buttons) which works on all platforms.

I want that Control Panel to be shared with everyone (PC users, Android users etc).

Once a person press a button, all of the users Control Panels will be updated.
How do I approach this issue?

Dedicated server with clients?
I'm looking for a block of code which handle sending/receiving data/click on a button.

The whole program written in Unity C# and I'd like a solution in this platform as well (if possible).

Answer (score 1):

socket programming is cross platform. you just send and recieve bytes. you just should have a server to recieve data and send it to other devices. if you use c# you can use .net sockets but for get rid of syncing problem yu can simply use unity Network library and using RPC. now unity has new network system named UNET and there is also photon. photon is not made by unity technologies but as the api is written for many different platform it can be the best choice for you to work on.